# Corrupted Laptop - Transfer Data Without My Computer (explorer.exe) Using Command Line

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, network-shares, file-transfer

I have a laptop (Toshiba Satellite) that is pretty messed up.  The person this belongs too already replaced it with a new machine.  My job is to transfer all her data from this machine to disk so that I can transfer it to her.  She doesn't want to lose any data (understandably so).

Any operation I attempted (i.e., double clicking on any folder icon, like My Documents, My Computer, etc) resulted in a complete crash.  The only good news is that I can actually start and navigate around using the command line.  Also, I can access the internet.

I have a network, so if I can map the drives I can get this thing figured out (hopefully).  Also, I tried a USB drive but I couldn't figure out how to access it from the command line.

Two questions (I need to use the command line for these):  How would I go about accessing the USB drive and how can I map the shared drives on my network so that I may `cd` to that directory for use of the `copy` command?

EDIT - sorry, yes, Windows XP Media Edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a WinXP machine.

- Use xcopy instead of copy.
- The USB drive should show up as another disk drive when you plug it in, like E: or something, just keep trying letters.
- You can map a network drive using `net use * \\server\share /u:Username` it will then ask you for the password, once it's mapped it will tell you what drive letter it ended up using.
- I'd start with a `chkdsk /f c:` and see what it finds.

Comment: Great idea.  I will try these alternatives.

Comment: If you can obtain it somewhere, you could use the newer Robocopy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Comment: The command `net use * \\server\share` worked like a charm.  I can now navigate to the directory and copy files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'd just boot it using [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/), and manipulate all the files that way.

Knoppix is a great tool for this sort of system recovery.

**Edit:** Yea, seems for me that the first thing on a laptop to go is always the optical drive...They just can't take the pain.

I've had some success with [booting Knoppix from a USB key](http://www.knoppix.net/wiki/Bootable_USB_Key). It'd be my preferred method if USB keys could be made read only...I'm all about read-only media for troubleshooting.

Comment: Good point.  I haven't confirmed whether the CD drive is operational.  This machine is real messed up.  Any launching of other than Command line and Chrome has caused nothing but trouble.  No IE, and I can't even install Firefox.  However, I will boot my version of Knoppix live to see of this works.

Comment: I've used Ubuntu 9.1 for this as well. Both the "bad" drive and the USB drive were recognized and available on boot; it was very easy to transfer from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

> Any operation I attempted (i.e.,
>   double clicking on any folder icon,
>   like My Documents, My Computer, etc)
>   resulted din a complete crash. The
>   only good news is that I can actually
>   start and navigate around using the
>   command line. Also, I can access the
>   internet.

That is most of the times a shell extension crashing, you could use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and sort on the Company field now you can select those that are not from Microsoft and disable those. Disabling non-microsoft services and start-up programs can also help to resolve in this problem, use [MSConfig](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310560) for that.

Reboot and enjoy a working Windows Explorer. ;-)

Comment: Yes, tried stopping services with task manager and msconfig.  This actually did help get the system less bogged down, but if I wasn't careful, I would cascade an entire mess of failed executables and complete system failure.  This machine was jacked, I tell ya! Thanks though...